# Cannot edit HTML in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am trying to make a custom question on Qualtrics, which consists of a slider and a canvas. The canvas responds to the slider input to change some drawing settings. the user has to choose what the best settings are according to them.

I have been able to enter the JavaScript in the Qualtrics question, but I am not able to enter the HTML I require for this question.

The HTML is the following:

```
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<input type="range" id="slider">
```

I am following [this tutorial](https://publicfragments.org/2015/02/06/using-the-qualtrics-javascript-api-to-create-visualizations/), but I have not been able to save the HTML. Each time I exit the editor I see "Click to write the question text". It's not just an editor bug, as I have tried just previewing the question immediately after exiting the editor.

I have tried editing the html to something simpler (I used a single  tag), and that worked. So my idea is that it blocks the canvas and the input slider.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you don't have HTML Markup privileges on your account. Ask your Qualtrics Brand Administrator to add that privilege.